# Android icon getting cut off [React Native]

Tags: android, reactjs, icons, expo, native

I just published my first App on Google Play, and everything seems good, except for the main icon. For some reason it keeps getting cut off on the edges. I have sized it to be 512x512 pixels in Photopea, and have tried making it smaller several times (the actual graphic within the 512x512 space), but nothing seems to make a difference.

How can I fix this? Please let me know if any details are needed. I am using Expo and have tried both `expo publish` and re-bundling and updating the app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I realise that this is an old question but I had the same issue and this question was among first results.

The problem is because your icon is near the edges of the image and it is being cut off by android.

The solution is following:

> It is recommended that you use a 1024x1024 png file,
> **leaving at least the outer 1/6 transparent on each side.**

Comment: woah, that's right ! Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive?authuser=1 "Both layers must be sized at 108 x 108 dp.
The inner 72 x 72 dp of the icon appears within the masked viewport.
The system reserves the outer 18 dp on **each of the 4 sides** to create interesting visual effects, such as parallax or pulsing."

Answer (score 0):

I have used 1024x1024 png file for app logo and now I am able see logo proper on both android mobiles and tablets